# Is this non-invasive?

Tags: solr, hdfs, apache-flink

I want to try apache flink, hadoop and solr for non-invasive ingestion of logs in order to process and index them and do some analytics and querying over.
I'm thinking about use flink for data processing of applications logs for several applications, then put them on hadoop and then querying them with solr.
Questions are: is this really non-invasive? Flink behaves like flume in the sense that agents are installes and configured in the servers that I like to monitor? And is hadoop and solr a good combination of indexing large amount of logs then querying it sql-style to gain insight into the data and make some predictions thar useful in creating alerts?

Thank you.

Comment: How does your current setup looks like? Do you already have a hadoop and a solr cluster running?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "invasive" in this context?

Comment: @DavidAnderson well it is kinda a legacy expression, but it means that the logging analytic utility won’t be in the same process that is actually writing the log and won’t locking the resource, but that is sort of a given because it is only reading the file.

Comment: @TobiSH no, I’m actually overviewing options from high altitude.

Comment: @Camilo In this case I would have a closer look at the ELK stack as recommended in the answer of Abhijit Bashetti

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest here to use the ELK stack. ELK stack is Elasticsearch, Logstash and Kibana.

`Logstash` : To ingest the data from any source to Elasticsearch. Source could be anything like RDBMS,File, MQ etc. Consider the destination as Elasticsearch.

In logstach you can configure the same by in conf file by mentioning the input and output. You can filter the data in logstash conf file.

`Elasticsearch` : Elasticsearch is a search engine based on the Lucene library. It provides a distributed, multitenant-capable full-text search engine with an HTTP web interface and schema-free JSON documents.
Once the the data is indexed on the Elasticsearch. You can fetch the data by Rest call. You can use the watcher feature of Elasticsearch and gets the alert/notification on some specific conditions.

`Kibana`:Kibana is an open source data visualization plugin for Elasticsearch. It provides visualization capabilities on top of the content indexed on an Elasticsearch cluster. Users can create bar, line and scatter plots, or pie charts and maps on top of large volumes of data.

You can ingest the data by using Apache Flink instead of Logstash.
Apache flink can ingest the data to Elasticsearch.
Here is the example of it.

[Apache Flink to Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/blog/building-real-time-dashboard-applications-with-apache-flink-elasticsearch-and-kibana)

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely look into that.

Comment: instead of logstash you can use the apache flink to ingest the data into the elasticsearch..

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/blog/building-real-time-dashboard-applications-with-apache-flink-elasticsearch-and-kibana

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at Flink's SQL support. Some companies are using this to do alerting and predictions. This would have the advantage of significantly simplifying your stack, as you wouldn't need hadoop or solr (or the ELK stack).